# how to download project from code.google?

Tags: tortoisesvn, google-code

i am using tortoise svn client to download code from code.google.If protocol is http i am able to download but how to download the code from url below.

hg clone https://vimeoid.googlecode.com/hg/vimeoid

thankx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hg represents a Mercurial repository, which is an alternative to subversion for source control, you'll need to download a mercurial client.

Mercurial can be downloaded at [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/).